# Monitoring Snowflake with Dynatrace

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynatrace

We have a managed deployment of dynatrace and I would like ot know if anyone has configured monitoring for Snowflake with the performance tool?

Please advise and thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have Dynatrace monitoring our ELT processes (which is pointing at snowflake), and monitoring our Reading processes (which is pointing at snowflake), and monitoring our Snowflake monitoring (which is collecting usage stats from snowflake), so in that sense we can see it in dynatrace, but we are not monitoring it like one of our own services.